# bower can't install dependencies

Tags: npm, bower, npm-install, bower-install

i'm trying to install bower via npm but nothing to happend when i run this command as root :

```
sudo npm  bower -g install
```

i get this in my console :

Usage: npm

```
where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, bin, bugs, c, cache, completion, config,
    ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, edit, explore, get,
    help, help-search, i, init, install, install-test, it, link,
    list, ln, logout, ls, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root, run,
    run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star, stars,
    start, stop, t, tag, team, test, tst, un, uninstall,
    unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view, whoami

npm <cmd> -h     quick help on <cmd>
npm -l           display full usage info
npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
npm help npm     involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /home/achraf/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@3.10.3 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

It is: `npm install -g bower`.  In your case you may preface it with `sudo`.

Edit:  The reason you see that npm output is because you're trying to run 'bower' as an npm command ('bower' is not an npm command), rather than running 'install' with bower as an option.

To install dependencies from `bower.json` go to your project folder and run `bower install`.

Comment: @Bobox - please 'tick' this as the selected answer. (:

Comment: Yes, but your command is not the same as mine.  Do this: `sudo npm install -g bower` (copy and paste that)

Comment: already use your command not working my bower not install my dependencies

Comment: it's showing `/usr/bin/bower -> /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
/usr/lib
└── bower@1.7.9`